# Something in my firefox profile that is making buttons larger

Tags: firefox

I have something in my firefox profile that is making buttons on websites appear larger than what they should be. I can't find the setting to change it back. Can someone help me with what it is pls? My buttons normally are less tall.

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your profile and let it make you a new default one ->

- Click the 3 lines icon
- Press ? -> Then select Troubleshoot Information
- Under 'Application Basics' click 'Show Folder' -> this will launch a windows folder with your profile, simply delete it (with firefox closed) and relaunch